# Connecting Something Big to an Arduino - Sending more than 5V

Tags: relay, transistor

So I am turning a relay on and off with my Arduino. I am using python to control it but wrote the simple basic code in the Arduino IDE. I am able to send 5 or 0 volts to the pin. My question is, how can I turn something on and off that requires more than 5 volts to turn on?

Thank you.

Comment: you need a relay shield

Comment: Many relays are controlled w a 5v signal, yet switch 120-240 volts on the second set of contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transistor, amplifier, opto-isolator or if you can drive a 5V relay use that relay to drive a higher voltage/current item item.